# Parse findInBackground doesn't add to global arraylist?

Tags: java, android, parse-platform

This is a snippet of my code with small edits in names.

```
String[] items;
ArrayList<String>tempListItems;

public void initList() {
        if(query()){
            items = new String[tempListItems.size()];
            items = tempListItems.toArray(items);
            Arrays.sort(items);

            Log.d("HSearch - initList", "Generate Clean List");
            Log.d("initList - temp size", Integer.toString(tempListItems.size()));
            Log.d("initList - items size", Integer.toString(items.length));
        }
    }

private boolean query() {
        tempListItems = new ArrayList<String>();
        ParseQuery<ParseObject> query = ParseQuery.getQuery("Table");
        query.orderByAscending("name");
        query.findInBackground(new FindCallback<ParseObject>() {
            @Override
            public void done(List<ParseObject> list, com.parse.ParseException e) {
                if (e == null) {
                    for (ParseObject name : list) {
                        tempListItems.add(name.getString("name"));
                    }
                } else {
                    Log.d("score", "Error: " + e.getMessage());
                }
            }
        });
        return true;
    }
```

My problem is in query(), if I check the size of tempListItems after done() the size is not empty.  However, once query() is done and I return back to initList(), if I check tempListItems again it is empty.

done() is a method within query().  I forgot the technical term of it!

I'm unsure of how to make sure changes to tempListItems during query() and done() stays after it returns.

Comment: and inside `done` method ?

Comment: done() is inside query(), sorry for the confusion

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
String[] items;
final ArrayList<String>tempListItems;
{
    tempListItems= new ArrayList<>();
}

public void initList() {
    if(query()){
        items = new String[tempListItems.size()];
        items = tempListItems.toArray(items);
        Arrays.sort(items);

        Log.d("HSearch - initList", "Generate Clean List");
        Log.d("initList - temp size", Integer.toString(tempListItems.size()));
        Log.d("initList - items size", Integer.toString(items.length));
    }
}

private boolean query() {
    ParseQuery<ParseObject> query = ParseQuery.getQuery("Table");
    query.orderByAscending("name");
    query.findInBackground(new FindCallback<ParseObject>() {
        @Override
        public void done(List<ParseObject> list, com.parse.ParseException e) {
            if (e == null) {
                for (ParseObject name : list) {
                    tempListItems.add(name.getString("name"));
                }
            } else {
                Log.d("score", "Error: " + e.getMessage());
            }
        }
    });
    return true;
}
```

> > Changed your code, this should work, as It worked for me.
> >
> > Make your methods public to use in other classes.

Answer (score 2):

How about creating a Handler before query.findInBackground :

```
Handler handler = new Handler();
```

and put the for loop inside handler.post(Runnable) :

```
handler.post(new Runnable(){
    @Override
    run(){
       for (ParseObject name : list)
           tempListItems.add(name.getString("name"));
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

As see here:

[findInBackground](https://parse.com/docs/android/api/com/parse/ParseQuery.html#findInBackground()) : *Retrieves a list of ParseObjects that satisfy this query from the source in a background thread.*

Means `findInBackground` method is running on different Thread from which calling `query.findInBackground` method.

> if I check the size of tempListItems after done() the size is not
>   empty

Here:

```
if(query()){
   //....
  }
```

if we check size of `tempListItems` inside `if-block` then size always `zero` because if block is executing just after starting `query.findInBackground` Thread without waiting for Result of Task.

`done` is a callback method which is called when `findInBackground` executing complete on same Thread which is started it.

Answer (score 1):

`query()` will return `true` without waiting of `done` response. that's why `list` is empty.

> put your code in `done` success

```
  private void query() {
    ParseQuery<ParseObject> query = ParseQuery.getQuery("Table");
    query.orderByAscending("name");
    query.findInBackground(new FindCallback<ParseObject>() {
        @Override
        public void done(List<ParseObject> list, com.parse.ParseException e) {
            if (e == null) {
                for (ParseObject name : list) {
                    tempListItems.add(name.getString("name"));
                }

                items = new String[tempListItems.size()];
                items = tempListItems.toArray(items);
                Arrays.sort(items);

                Log.d("HSearch - initList", "Generate Clean List");
                Log.d("initList - temp size",
                        Integer.toString(tempListItems.size()));
                Log.d("initList - items size",
                        Integer.toString(items.length));
            } else {
                Log.d("score", "Error: " + e.getMessage());
            }
        }
    });
}
```