# Unable to add to ArrayList<String> inside done function in new FindCallback<ParseUser>

Tags: java, android, parsing, arraylist, parse-platform

```
public class UserActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    ArrayAdapter arrayAdapter;
    ListView listView;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_user);

        listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView);
        final ArrayList<String> userList;
        {
            userList = new ArrayList<>();
        }
        arrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, userList);

        ParseQuery<ParseUser> query = ParseUser.getQuery();

        // findInBackground tries to find it amongst all the items in the query while getInBackground has two param where you are expected to know the ID of the item
        query.findInBackground(new FindCallback<ParseUser>() {
            @Override
            public void done(List<ParseUser> objects, ParseException e) {
                if (e == null) {
                    for (ParseUser user : objects) {
                        Log.i("usernames", user.getUsername());
                        userList.add(user.getUsername());
                    }
                }
                else {
                    Log.i("Error", e.getMessage());
                }
            }
        });

        for (int i = 0; i < userList.size(); i++) {
            Log.i("userList", userList.get(i));
        }

        if (userList.isEmpty()) {
            Log.i("userList", "WTF HOW?");
        }

        // Set the listView
        arrayAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
        listView.setAdapter(arrayAdapter);
    }
}
```

For some reason, "userList" always logs "WTF HOW" which is printed when userList is empty. However, "usernames" is able to correctly log all the user.getUsernames in the parse server. I looked at [Parse findInBackground doesn't add to global arraylist?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33886450/parse-findinbackground-doesnt-add-to-global-arraylist) which had a similiar question but the answers did not help me. What am I doing here that makes the userList turn up empty? I tried putting the userList as global variable at first but that didn't work either.

Comment: `findInBackground()` runs the query asynchronously, so your list won't have been populated when you try to use it immediately after. Move the `arrayAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged()` call - and whatever else needs the list items, if anything - to the `done()` method, after the `for` loop.

Comment: So are you saying that your arraylist has items but the if statement `.isEmpty()` is still returning false?

Comment: @MikeM. Thanks! I had to move everything to the done() method and everything else changed to final and then it worked.